# Unable to start debugging with GDB, path is missing or invalid

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I have a problem with debugging my code with GDB. I have compiled the C file and the executable file has been created, yet the path to it seems to not exist when I try to debug it. Do you have any suggestions why is that?

** [image]**

Comment: What is your error message? Does it complain about path to `gdb` or path to your program?

Comment: @Gerhardh about path to my program

Comment: Did compilation work properly? Any error messages you might have missed? In what folder is your executable if you check in file browser?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes the compilation worked properly, it said that build finished successfully. The executable is in same folder as the C file, the workspaceFolder

Comment: Maybe your problem is created by using spaces in the file name or path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in unicode characters. I had special characters in my path so GDB could not interpret it